# How to mount USB on ESXi 4.1?

Tags: vmware-esxi, mount, usb

This is what I tried but it doesn't work :

1. Connect with SSH
2. `# /etc/init.d/usbarbitrator stop`
3. `# fdisk -l |grep Disk`

   Disk /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0: 4022 MB, 4022337024 bytes
4. `# ls /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0*`

   /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0
   /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0:4
5. `# mkdir /mnt/usb`
6. `# mount /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0 /mnt/usb`

   mount: mounting /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0 on /mnt/usb failed: No such file or directory
7. Also tried with /dev/disks/mpx.vmhba40:C0:T0:L0:4, with /mnt/usb/, always the same error message.
8. Then I checked `# ls -l /vmfs/volumes`, but it wasn't there either

The version of ESXi is 4.1...
USB Key is FAT32 as far as I know.

Any help or advice would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this [VMware KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1036340) article it looks like it should be a FAT 16 formatted USB drive

> The USB key or disk device media is formatted with a FAT16 partition
>   and is of maximum size 2GB

Update:
Looking at this [blog post](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2012/03/how-to-access-usb-storage-in-esxi-shell.html) the drive would need to be FAT16, Which would make sense to me as VMware made ESXi as small footprint they can which would mean not including unneeded things in the kernel such as file system drivers.

Comment: Yes I saw that article, but it wasn't clear if this statement was a problem or a requirement.

Comment: Looks to me like a requirement.

Comment: Updated answer with another article I found.